# Remote Config throttling : The counter is per device or sum all calls?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

The documentation says:

> If an app fetches too many times in a short time period, fetch calls
> are throttled and the SDK returns
> FirebaseRemoteConfigFetchThrottledException. Before SDK version
> 17.0.0, the limit was 5 fetch requests in a 60 minute window (newer versions have more permissive limits).

This policy consider the fetch from all devices and running Apps on my project or the counter is by device?

For example, 5 different devices call fetch using my App. If a sixth device call again, in less than 1 hour, will be throttled ? Or each device can fetch 5 times before be throttled ?

Background:

I have implemented the "real time propagation" for remote config, as described on the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/propagate-updates-realtime) and [here](https://medium.com/iguanafix-engineering/real-time-remote-config-on-ios-f6d3ca35e8dc)

Is working correctly.

When i publish a new configuration, my app receive a silent notification. I set one flag to indicate that a new update is available and then. When user opens the App again, i verify the flag, set the fetchInterval to 0 and  force fetch configuration from the firebase server. But im worried that this strategy might be throttled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this answer comes a bit late but in case someone else is useful the throttled state is **by device**, I was able to check this for myself, debugging with other devices at the same time that one of my devices was in the throttled state. You can also check for yourself by removing the application and installing it again. Firebase will take your device as a new one and it will no longer be in a throttled state.

Comment: Thanks, in my experience, was always by device too. This should be more clear on documentation.